# Why Ng-Idle not working on iOS when app is in background mode for ionic 4?

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, angular6, ionic4

I am using Ng-Idle for session time-out functionality. it’s working fine in android for both foreground and background mode of the app but in iOS 13 it is only working when the app is in foreground mode but if I run the app in background mode its not working code is written inside the idle.onTimeout is not working.

If anyone knows how to solve it or about something that can help with that, I’ll be glad to read about it.

```
 Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 5.2.7
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.11.5
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.803.19
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.1.3
   @angular/cli                  : 8.3.19
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.1.1

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : android 8.1.0
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.3, (and 20 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res : 0.8.1
   native-run  : 0.2.9

System:

   NodeJS : v10.15.3 
   npm    : 6.4.1
   OS     : Windows 10
```

Here is the code

```
 setIdle() {
  this.idle.setIdle(5); 
  this.idle.setTimeout(5);
  this.idle.setInterrupts(DEFAULT_INTERRUPTSOURCES);
  this.idle.onTimeout.subscribe(() => {
    console.log("Idle Timed Out");
  });
  this.idle.watch();
```

}

Comment: Hi @sachin Joshi, even I'm facing same problem. Have you found the solution to this ?

Comment: @Sachin how did you resolve this. I am facing the same issue.